# scavage website with simple dom takes to long, need help or other solution

Tags: php, dom

I want to scavage some dates from a website for reference it this page: [Roskilde Festival Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roskilde_Festival)
I'm using simple dom parser and have this php page:

```
<?php
require "HtmlDomParser.php";
use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;
$html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roskilde_Festival');
$table = $html->find('.wikitable',1);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
$data= array();
foreach($row->find('td') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
    $columnNumbers = [ 1, 2 ];
    // push the cell's text to the array
    if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
        $text = $cell->plaintext;
        $data[] = explode("[",$text)[0];
    }
}
$rowData[] = $data;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
echo '<tr>'; 
foreach ($tr as $td)
    echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

It gives me what I need:
2013 29 June – 7 July
2014 29 June – 6 July
2015 27 June – 4 July
2016 25 June – 3 July
2017 24 June - 1 July
2018 30 June - 7 July

but I also get this error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in   C:\sample\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php on line 140

What can I do to make it faster, and by faster I'm hoping for max 2 seconds.
Do I need to run a cron job that saves the data or is there faster way?

Comment: Have you tested this with and without the post processing? Doing so will tell you if it's your processing tr/td that is slow or if it's the HtmlDomParser that is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied your code and used the latest version of this HtmlParser from the github repo. Your code runs in under two seconds for me.

I would guess, that you have xdebug enabled. This often causes such performance drawbacks. Try this without xdebug.

If you already have xdebug disabled, which PHP-version are you running?

Comment: @user9995893 then consider accepting my answer for reward? ;-)